Is there an easy way to statically type the resolver in wretch (using generics or otherwise) for Typescript?
I'm replacing my fetch calls with wretch and I want to type the resolver so that I can migrate cleanly and ensure type safety for my api calls.
I've discovered two ways to do it but neither are ideal.
Method 1: resolve every request with a type argument to .json()
At the top layer
import wretch from "wretch";
import FormDataAddon from "wretch/addons/formData";
import QueryStringAddon from "wretch/addons/queryString";


export const apiUntyped = wretch("api-url")
  .errorType("json")
  .addon(FormDataAddon)
  .addon(QueryStringAddon);            // no .resolve() helper

Usage
export const getUsers = async (): Promise<User[]> =>
  await apiUntyped.get("/users").json<User[]>();       // <---- add the type arg here

This works but then I have to call .json<T>() for every api call which I was hoping to avoid by using the .resolve() helper. However, that creates other problems.
Method 2: use generics to type the resolve helper
At the top layer
import wretch, { Wretch } from "wretch";
import FormData, { FormDataAddon } from "wretch/addons/formData";
import QueryString, { QueryStringAddon } from "wretch/addons/queryString";

export function apiTyped<T>(): QueryStringAddon &
  FormDataAddon &
  Wretch<FormDataAddon & QueryStringAddon, unknown, Promise<Awaited<T>>> {
  return wretch("api-url")
    .errorType("json")
    .resolve((r) => r.json<T>())              // <--- add the type arg here
    .addon(FormData)
    .addon(QueryString);
}

Usage
export const getUsers = async (): Promise<User[]> =>
  await apiTyped<User[]>().get("/users");              // no .json() call

Now I don't have to call the .json() helper but as you can see the explicit return type for the apiTyped factory is horrendous and gets worse the more addons are used. Obviously I could simply delete the explicit return type and it'll work but I'm not sure that's necessarily any better :)
What doesn't work
import wretch from "wretch";
import FormDataAddon from "wretch/addons/formData";
import QueryStringAddon from "wretch/addons/queryString";

export const apiUntypedWithResolver = wretch("api-url")
  .errorType("json")
  .resolve((r) => r.json())
  .addon(FormDataAddon)
  .addon(QueryStringAddon);

This won't work
export const getUsers = async (): Promise<User[]> =>
  await apiUntypedWithResolver.get("/users");

"unknown is not assignable to type User[]"
And this won't work
export const getUsers = async (): Promise<User[]> =>
  await apiUntypedWithResolver.get("/users").json<User[]>();

"Expected 0 type arguments but got 1".

When I was using fetch I didn't explicitly type the fetch() call and typescript simply accepted the explicit typing of Promise<User[]>. Then when I was developing downstream Typescript treated the value as a User[].

So is this how wretch was intended to be used? This is my first time using wretch so I might just be missing something. I searched the web but couldn't find any typescript examples and zero threads on this topic. The typescript documentation for wretch is a vey bare bones reference so I wasn't able to glean anything from that.
Aside from the syntax, is ensuring the static type safety here overkill? Should I add a separate step after these functions return to narrow the types so they are easier to work with downstream?
Thanks for taking a look and for any help or advice.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you don't get enough engagement here, it's because there aren't enough wretch experts who also know TypeScript enough to help. Which means you'll either need to go elsewhere for help, or try to [edit] the question to be a [mre] without a dependency on wretch, say by providing a skeleton of the typings here, enough to reproduce your issue in a standalone IDE. Even if it depends on wretch you still probably want to give us your other definitions like whatever User is.  Not sure how to help, but good luck!

FYI, I created dr-fetch for the sole purpose of being able to specify all possible body types depending on the HTTP status code.

For anyone in the future who is curious, I ended up doing the type inference as part of parsing the response (with zod in this case).
export async function getUsers(): Promise<User[]> {
  const res = await api.get("/users");
  const parsed = userSchema.array().safeParse(res);

  if (!parsed.success) {
    throw new Error(`Users "${res}" is not valid.`);
  }

  return parsed.data;
}

Happy coding!
